Jetpack Compose Text Styles(Strikethrough, Underline) issue
I am facing some unexpected TextStyle behaviour while applying different styles in Jetpack Compose.

This is my code:
@Composable
fun TextDecorationExample() {
    var isUnderlined by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var isStrikethrough by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var isBold by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var isItalic by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()

    Column(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(16.dp)
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(200.dp) //Remove
                .border(2.dp, Color.White)
                .padding(10.dp)
                .verticalScroll(scrollState) //Remove
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Hello, Jetpack Compose! " +
                        "This is a long text to demonstrate vertical scrolling. " +
                        "You can apply various text styles like underline, strikethrough, bold, and italic.",
                color = Color.White,
                style = TextStyle(
                    fontSize = 24.sp,
                    textDecoration = when {
                        isUnderlined && isStrikethrough -> TextDecoration.Underline + TextDecoration.LineThrough
                        isUnderlined -> TextDecoration.Underline
                        isStrikethrough -> TextDecoration.LineThrough
                        else -> null
                    },
                    fontWeight = if (isBold) FontWeight.Bold else FontWeight.Normal,
                    fontStyle = if (isItalic) FontStyle.Italic else FontStyle.Normal
                ),
                modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 16.dp)
            )
        }

        Button(onClick = { isUnderlined = !isUnderlined },
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                contentColor = if (isUnderlined) Color.Black else Color.White,
                containerColor = if (isUnderlined) Color.Green else Color.Gray
            ),
            modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 8.dp)) {
            Text(text = "Underline")
        }

        Button(onClick = { isStrikethrough = !isStrikethrough },
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                contentColor = if (isStrikethrough) Color.Black else Color.White,
                containerColor = if (isStrikethrough) Color.Green else Color.Gray
            ),
            modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 8.dp)) {
            Text(text = "Strikethrough")
        }

        Button(onClick = { isBold = !isBold },
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                contentColor = if (isBold) Color.Black else Color.White,
                containerColor = if (isBold) Color.Green else Color.Gray
            ),
            modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 8.dp)) {
            Text(text = "Bold")
        }

        Button(onClick = { isItalic = !isItalic },
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                contentColor = if (isItalic) Color.Black else Color.White,
                containerColor = if (isItalic) Color.Green else Color.Gray
            ),
            modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 8.dp)
        ) {
            Text(text =  "Italic")
        }
    }
}

I have noticed that if I remove height and verticalScroll from theBox Composable, it's working fine. However, I need fixed height with scroll.
How to resolve this?

I just tested your code (thanks for the great sample btw), but I can't reproduce the issue. On which Compose version are you? Please try adding implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.7.0-rc01" to your dependencies, this is the latest version.

@BenjyTec Thanks. I have Updated platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2024.08.00') and Now it's working fine

Happy to hear that updating the dependencies solved it. I added an answer below for completeness. You can mark it as accepted answer by clicking the checkmark at the left side of the answer if you want.

It turns out that this issue is resolved by updating the dependencies.  It is enough to update your build.gradle to
val composeBom = platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2024.08.00")
implementation(composeBom)

or
implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.6.8"

respectively.
